# How to create a Rest Api for triggering a process

Tags: rest, web-services

I want to create an endpoint which expected to be triggered by consumer to start some process. What rules should be applied to it so it could be called a Restful endpoint?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261552/which-http-verb-should-i-use-to-trigger-an-action-in-a-rest-web-service